# Can't edit module in existing project

Tags: vb6, editor

I have an existing project in Visual Basic 6.0.

When I try to edit any code block in a form of the project, it gives an error saying;

> Can't edit module.

Comment: Make sure the physical files do not have the read-only attribute

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you haven't opened your project in read only. Go to the project properties and uncheck "Read Only".

Answer (score 1):

I also ran into this error when I needed to unbind a VB6 project from Visual Source Safe.

As discussed in [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/282816), I needed to delete the Vssver.scc and Mssccprj.scc files and then uncheck the read-only property for each of my files as Alex said.

Answer (score 0):

I also run to this error and solution was to close all files and then restart instance of Visual Studio 6.